# Content seems to be hidden while using Python and Selenium for webscraping

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the price of this [page](https://www.gem.xyz/collection/official-v1-punks/). I am able to see the element from inspection under Google Chrome.

[image]

And as such I copied the Xpath and CSS selector as follows:

css selector - `#app > div > div.inline-flex.items-between.relative.h-full.flex-col.md\:flex-row.justify-between.swap > div.flex.flex-col.justify-between.flex-shrink.max-w-full.w-full.min-w-0 > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.mason.w-full.px-3 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div.p-2.w-full > div.flex.justify-between.items-center.text-sm.text-gray-600.dark\:text-gray-300.h-7 > div > div > div > div`

Xpath - `//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div`

Full Xpath - `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div`

And my code

```
import sys
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Control panel
headless_webdriver_switch = True
print_switch = True
sole_print_switch = False
if sole_print_switch:
    print_switch = False

# Main
main_url = 'https://www.gem.xyz/collection/official-v1-punks/'
current_path = os.getcwd()
driver_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'chrome_driver', 'chromedriver.exe')
options = Options()

if headless_webdriver_switch:
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1200')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get(main_url)

if print_switch:
    print(driver.page_source)

# Search elements
# Using CSS selector
curr_css_selector = '#app > div > div.inline-flex.items-between.relative.h-full.flex-col.md\:flex-row.justify-between.swap > div.flex.flex-col.justify-between.flex-shrink.max-w-full.w-full.min-w-0 > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.mason.w-full.px-3 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div.p-2.w-full > div.flex.justify-between.items-center.text-sm.text-gray-600.dark\:text-gray-300.h-7 > div > div > div > div'
elements_by_css_selector = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(curr_css_selector)
print(elements_by_css_selector)

# Using XPATH
curr_xpath = '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div'
curr_full_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div'
elements_by_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath(curr_xpath)
print(elements_by_xpath)

driver.quit()
```

`print(driver.page_source)` results (not shown due to size) does NOT seem to contain the prices.

The `print(elements_by_css_selector)` resulted in empty list `[]`

And `print(elements_by_xpath)` resulted in the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.91)
```

Why is the content not shown in `driver.page_source`, and how can I extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the following is how you can solve it using the requests module:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://gem-api-v2-2.herokuapp.com/assets'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-api-key': 'rLnNH1tdrT09EQjGsjrSS7V3uGonfZLW',
    'Origin': 'https://www.gem.xyz'
}

params = {"filters":{"traits":{},"traitsRange":{},"slug":"official-v1-punks","rankRange":{},"price":{}},"sort":{"currentEthPrice":"asc"},"fields":{"id":1,"name":1,"address":1,"collectionName":1,"collectionSymbol":1,"externalLink":1,"imageUrl":1,"smallImageUrl":1,"animationUrl":1,"openRarityRank":1,"standard":1,"perItemEthPrice":1,"market":1,"pendingTrxs":1,"currentBasePrice":1,"paymentToken":1,"marketUrl":1,"marketplace":1,"tokenId":1,"priceInfo":1,"tokenReserves":1,"ethReserves":1,"sudoPoolAddress":1,"sellOrders":1,"startingPrice":1,"rarityScore":1},"offset":0,"limit":30,"markets":[],"status":["buy_now"]}

def get_price(item):
    price =  str(float(item) / 1000000000000000000)[:6]
    return price

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    while True:
        res = s.post(link,json=params)
        if not res.json()['data']:
            break
        for item in res.json()['data']:
            item_name = item['name']
            item_price = get_price(item['priceInfo']['price'])
            print((item_name,item_price))

        params['offset']+=30
```

Output:

```
('V1 PUNK #4931', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #1512', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #5340', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #6933', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #1927', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #8154', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #4972', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #5947', '4.7515')
('V1 PUNK #1306', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #1466', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #1778', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #2043', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #7957', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #9419', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #3418', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #6517', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #6825', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #8798', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #1277', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #2037', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #2999', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #2972', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #2959', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #2970', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #2772', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #3357', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #3312', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #3219', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #3261', '4.7705')
('V1 PUNK #3286', '4.7705')
```

Comment: It seems to work, do you mind explain how you figured out the structure of `params`? And could you advice how I should approach to pulling more data in this infinite scrolling page?

Comment: I've edited the code above to fetch content after doing infinite scrolling @KubiK888. As for figuring out the structure of params, you should give [this link](https://support.deskpro.com/en/kb/articles/how-to-inspect-ajax-requests-with-chrome-tools) a go to see how the requests are being issued. Given you have already gone through the article, when you click on the relevant url under the name column, you will be able to find out the url, params, headers, e.t.c.

Comment: great thanks. I got most of where they came from learning from the link, they are from `Response` of the `assets`. However, I can't figure out where you get `currentEthPrice`, `status`, and `markets`

Comment: [Here](https://ibb.co/m6FPvbS) you can find the whereabouts of those keys along with their values.

Answer (score 1):

The main hindrance here is `html element selection`. You can see in chrome devtools that the element locator select the element but the same price tag and its atttr also select others text node value. So I use selenium with bs4 the reason is bs4 is super powerful to grab the html contents.

**Working code as an example:**

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
url ='https://www.gem.xyz/collection/official-v1-punks/'


driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")

e=[] 

for card in soup.select('div[class="p-2 w-full"]'):
    p = card.select_one('div[class="flex gap-2 items-center mb-1"]+div > div > div > div > div')
    p= p.get_text(strip=True) if p else None

    d={
        "price":p
        }
    e.append(d)


df= pd.DataFrame(e)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    price
0   4.7515
1   4.7515
2   4.7515
3   4.7705
4   4.7705
5   4.7705
6   4.7705
7   4.7705
8   4.7705
9   4.7705
10  4.7515
11  4.7515
12  4.7515
13  4.7705
14  4.7705
15  4.7705
16  4.7705
17  4.7705
18  4.7705
19  4.7705
20  4.7515
21  4.7515
22  4.7705
23  4.7705
24  4.7705
25  4.7705
26  4.7705
27  4.7705
28  4.7705
29  4.7705
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the price:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Control panel
headless_webdriver_switch = True
print_switch = True
sole_print_switch = False
if sole_print_switch:
    print_switch = False

# Main
main_url = 'https://www.gem.xyz/collection/official-v1-punks/'
current_path = os.getcwd()
driver_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'chrome_driver', 'chromedriver.exe')
options = Options()

if headless_webdriver_switch:
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1200')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get(main_url)

if print_switch:
    print(driver.page_source)


row = 1
column = 1

price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[" + str(column) + "]/div[" + str(row) + "]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div").text

driver.quit()
```

For example, to find the price in the 2nd row and 3rd column, you would set row to 2 and column to 3. Hope this helps!

Comment: doesn't work, mine says `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.91)`

Comment: That's probably because the column or the row are out of range